# Read Large File and Insert inside Room Database

Tags: android, android-room

I am making an app that blocks inappropriate websites for parental control, I have the blocked websites in a text file which 50MB in size. I want to add them all to room database so that I can check if a url is blocked or not.

But reading and looping through each line in the text file taking forever, is there any better way I can read the file and add each line to room database?

```java
FileInputStream inputStream = null;
Scanner sc = null;
try {
    inputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
    sc = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8");
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        // insert to room database
    }
    // note that Scanner suppresses exceptions
    if (sc.ioException() != null) {
        throw sc.ioException();
    }
} finally {
    if (inputStream != null) {
        inputStream.close();
    }
    if (sc != null) {
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: `I have the blocked websites in a text file which 50MB in size.`. You mean the urls of the websites? That would be 500 thousand urls/sites then. How did you manage to write them down?

Comment: I used a python script to fetch those url from the internet, if it's python I can use like python sqlite atomic commit, to insert all of them really fast, but not sure about room database in android

Answer (score 0):

Make it as json and place it your project..
And when starting the application show a syncing state and load data to db ..
Do this only once.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options. As previously stated you could load the websites into json. This website should help automate that a bit. https://pdfmall.com/txt-to-json. This approach would still lead to an O(n) time complexity for searching.

While it will take a bit of memory, the method I'd recommend would be to build a custom object that holds all of those lines as Strings. Every time you start the app you would need to rebuild this object, but that's better than scanning constantly. You could implement an Async thread to do this in the background.

If you take this approach I would recommend storing them in a Olog(n) data structure like a binary tree. You don't want to just throw them into an Arraylist of strings, because then you'd be doing the same thing and having to scan through the entire array. If you store them in a tree, ordered by alphabetical order or perhaps length - whatever you want to do- then you reduce your search complexity from O(n) to Olog(n). Keep in mind when using custom objects, if you intend to pass them between Activities, you will need to implement Parcelable or another method.

Third you could use an Sql database, but in your case I don't believe this would speed anything up, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the urls in the text file sorted alphabetically.

Load the file in a string array list.

Do a simple binary search in the sorted list to check for an specific url.